# Android: Custom Filter not showing results, .clear() and .addAll() are there

Tags: android, filter

For my custom Adapter, I want to be able to filter the items in a ListView. I implemented Filterable, and created a Filter.

Here's my publishResults:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
{
    MainActivity.this.filteredPetList.clear();
    MainActivity.this.filteredPetList.addAll((ArrayList<Pet>)results.values);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If I check filteredPetList after

```
MainActivity.this.filteredPetList.addAll((ArrayList<Pet>)results.values);
```

, results show just fine, but the adapter won't update the view.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm probably doing something stupid again.

-Edit-
In my adapter I overrode notifyDataSetChanged, to see if it is actually called. It says:

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged()
{
    System.out.println("Notified...");
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I do get a result whenever I try to filter, notifyDataSetChanged gets called. I also checked if my filteredPetList was actually being changed outside the Filter, and it is.

It's just that the views don't update for some reason...

-Edit- Added full Adapter code:

```
private class PetAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
{
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    List<Row> rows;
    ArrayList<Integer> petIds;
    boolean clickable;
    PetFilter petFilter;

    public PetAdapter(ArrayList<Pet> petList, boolean clickable)
    {
        this.clickable = clickable;
        rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
        this.petIds= new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(Pet p : petList)
        {
            rows.add(new ImageTextTextRow(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this), p.getPetImageId(), p.getPetName(), p.getPetFood()));
            petIds.add(p.getPetId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        //Can do that certain items ARE enabled by using the position
        return clickable;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return RowType.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return rows.get(position).getViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return rows.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return rows.get(position).getView(convertView);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public int getSelectedPetId(int position)
    {
        return petIds.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if (petFilter == null)
            petFilter  = new PetFilter();

        return petFilter;
    }

    private class PetFilter extends Filter
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (MainActivity.this.filteredPetList == null)
            {
                synchronized (PetAdapter.this.lock)
                { 
                    MainActivity.this.filteredPetList = new ArrayList<Pet>(MainActivity.this.originalPetList);
                }
            }

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0)
            {
                synchronized (PetAdapter.this.lock)
                {
                    results.values = MainActivity.this.originalPetList;
                    results.count = MainActivity.this.originalPetList.size();
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                String constraintString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

                final ArrayList<Pet> items = MainActivity.this.filteredPetList;
                final int count = items.size();
                final ArrayList<Pet> newItems = new ArrayList<Pet>(count);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    final Pet item = items.get(i);
                    final String itemName = item.getPetName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

                    if (itemName.startsWith(constraintString))
                    {
                        newItems.add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        final String[] words = itemName.split(" ");
                        final int wordCount = words.length;
                        for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++)
                        {
                            if (words[k].startsWith(constraintString))
                            {
                                newItems.add(item);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                results.values = newItems;
                results.count = newItems.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            MainActivity.this.filteredPetList.clear();
            MainActivity.this.filteredPetList.addAll((ArrayList<Pet>)results.values);

            if (results.count > 0)
                PetAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            else
                PetAdapter.this.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Tregan

Comment: Please post the full code of your adapter.

Comment: Done. Added it as an edit.

Comment: The behavior is normal. You filter and update a list from the `MainActivity` but your entire adapter is based on a completely new list that you create, `rows`, so the filtered results will not be seen by the adapter. Also, I hope `ImageTextTextRow` isn't some kind of row and you're storing it in that list because this would a bad thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for this post, you made me see what was going on. It's working now.biter

ImageTextTextRow is indeed a row for the ListView, which displays an icon(ImageView)/petName(TextView)/petFood(TextView) in a single row. Is there a better way to make custom ListView rows?

Comment: A question is not supposed to include the solution to it. If your find the answer to your own question, you should write it as answer. This is encouraged, assuming you give proper credit to the other answers that helped you.

Comment: Create the custom view in the `getView()` method. There is a google i/o video called `The world of ListView` you should watch it for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to Luksprog, see his comment on my question.
I have changed my Adapter around and now it it's working fine. I also added some more code, and cleaned up, so it's a little bit different than before, but it should be clear what I changed when you read Luksprog's comment and then my code.

```
private class PetAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
{
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private List<Row> rows;
    private ArrayList<Integer> petIds;
    private boolean clickable;
    private ArrayList<Pet> filteredPetList;
    private PetFilter petFilter;

    public PetAdapter(boolean clickable)
    {
        this.rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
        this.petIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        this.clickable = clickable;
        this.filteredPetList = new ArrayList<Pet>(MainActivity.this.petList);

        createPetRows();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        //Can do that certain items ARE enabled/disabled by using the position
        return clickable;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return RowType.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return rows.get(position).getViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return rows.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        return rows.get(position).getView(convertView);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the petId for the selected row
     * @param position the position in the list
     * @return the petId that belongs to that row
     */
    public int getSelectedPetId(int position)
    {
        return petIds.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Creates rows that are displayed from items in the filteredPetList
     * Also adds petIds to a List, so that the selected pet can be found
     */
    private void createPetRows()
    {
        //Clear all current data
        rows.clear();
        petIds.clear();

        for(Pet p : filteredPetList)
        {
            rows.add(new ImageTextTextRow(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this), p.getPetImageId(), p.getPetName(), p.getPetFood()));
            petIds.add(p.getPetId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if (petFilter == null)
            petFilter  = new PetFilter();

        return petFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Custom Filter for our PetAdapter
     * @author Bas
     *
     */
    private class PetFilter extends Filter
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (PetAdapter.this.filteredPetList == null)
            {
                synchronized (PetAdapter.this.lock)
                {
                    PetAdapter.this.filteredPetList = new ArrayList<Pet>(MainActivity.this.petList);
                }
            }

            //No constraint is sent to filter by so we're going to send back the original array
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0)
            {
                synchronized (PetAdapter.this.lock)
                {
                    results.values = MainActivity.this.petList;
                    results.count = MainActivity.this.petList.size();
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                String constraintString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

                ArrayList<Pet> itemsToCheck = MainActivity.this.petList;

                final ArrayList<Pet> newFilteredPets = new ArrayList<Pet>(itemsToCheck.size());
                for(Pet p : itemsToCheck)
                {
                    final String petName = p.getPetName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    final String petFood = p.getPetFood().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

                    // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                    if (petName.startsWith(constraintString) || petFood.startsWith(constraintString))
                        newFilteredPets.add(p);
                    else
                    {
                        final String[] petNameWords = petName.split(" ");
                        final String[] petFoodWords = petFood.split(" ");
                        for (String s : petNameWords)
                        {
                            if (s.startsWith(constraintString))
                            {
                                newFilteredPets.add(p);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        for (String s : petFoodWords)
                        {
                            if (s.startsWith(constraintString))
                            {
                                newFilteredPets.add(p);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Set the result
                results.values = newFilteredPets;
                results.count = newFilteredPets.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            //Add the results to our filteredPetList
            PetAdapter.this.filteredPetList.clear();
            PetAdapter.this.filteredPetList.addAll((ArrayList<Pet>)results.values);

            //Create rows for every filtered Pet
            createPetRows();

            //Notify the Adapter
            if (results.count > 0)
                PetAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            else
                PetAdapter.this.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

            //Update the tvResults TextView with the amount of results found
            TextView tvResults = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResults);

            if(results.count < MainActivity.this.petList.size())
            {
                tvResults.setText(results.count + " results found.");
                tvResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                tvResults.setText("");
                tvResults.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May you only need call notifyDataSetChanged() from your adapter.

Comment: Check my edit, I checked if notifyDataSetChanged() gets called, and it gets called just fine :/

Answer (score -1):

I'll just give you my working custom filter code:

```
 public class NaamFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FillArray();
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String naam : namenarraylist) {
                if(naam.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    filtered.add(naam);
                }
            }
            results.values = filtered;
            results.count = filtered.size();
            return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        if (results.count == 0) {
            namenarraylist.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            namenarraylist = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, still have the same problem that the list just won't show the filtered results